# $u = 0$ is the only solution to the homogeneous Helmholtz equation $\Delta u + k^2 u = 0$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, integral-equations, wave-equation, greens-function, electromagnetism

We have that the solution to the inhomogeneous Helmholtz equation

$$\Delta u + k^2 u = f$$

can be represented by

$$u(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^3}G(x - y) f(y) dy$$

where $G$ is the fundamental solution of the Helmholtz equation.

But doesn't this imply that

$$\Delta u + k^2 u = 0$$

only has the solution $u = 0$? But this doesn't make sense as

Edit: The Sommerfeld radiation condition applies.

Comment: The question is unfinished, but something you should know is that Green's functions, what you call the "fundamental solution", depend on boundary conditions. For example, say you are working in $x_3>0$ with the boundary condition that $u(x_1,x_2,x_3=0)=f(x_1,x_2)$. Then, if $G_0$ is the Green's function in the unbounded space, $$G(x,y) = G_0(x,y) - G_0(x, y_1, y_2, -y_3).$$

Comment: @SeanLake I've edited the post to mention that the Sommerfeld radiation condition applies. So is $u = 0$ the only solution?

Answer (score 1):

To construct $G$, you needed to impose Sommerfeld's radiation condition which restricts the class of solutions that you could consider. Hence I believe $u=0$ is the only solution to the homogeneous problem in this restricted class.

Comment: ["In 1912 Sommerfeld introduced his radiation condition to ensure the uniqueness of the solution of certain exterior boundary value problems in mathematical physics."](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/031508609290004U) Hence, this argument applies only to such problems and not to the Helmholtz equation in general.

Comment: The case consider, you need the condition to construct the Green's function.

Comment: You don't need the condition. You impose the condition to satisfy some assumptions (there are other exterior boundary problems; the OP question is lacking details). Happily enough, the condition ensures uniqueness (showing what a smart guy Sommerfeld was).

Comment: @Pragabhava I agree with you that Sommefeld's radiation condition is a sufficient but not necessary (probability not necessary). However, when I read the post, I made the assumption (which could be false) that eurocoder was referring to $G(x)=\frac{e^{ik|x|}}{4\pi|x|}$, which is the consequence of the radiation condition.

Comment: True, and that's why I'm voting to close the incomplete question.

Comment: Sure. Nevertheless, it's probably a common problem that many people are stuck on.

Comment: @JackyChong But the homogeneous Helmholtz equation, with Sommerfeld radiation condition, is used everywhere in electromagnetics and acoustics to model the propagation of time-harmonic waves. I can't imagine $u=0$ is the only solution when it is used so much?